# .htaccess rewrite rule not working properly. Redirects to absolute path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess placed in server.com/site_admin/api (actual directory structure: /public_html/site_admin/api)

I want to direct all requests to the corresponding php file. So api/users would rewrite to api/users.php

So I wrote this rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But it doesn't work. I get a 404 when I access the url server.com/site_admin/users

When I added a [R=301] to it

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301]
```

I found that it redirects to http://server.com/home/server_user/public_html/site_admin/api/users.php
Instead of http://server.com/site_admin/api/users.php

Can someone please help me out here

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Yours doesn't work because the rewrited url is still matched by `(.*)`, so it will rewrite it again until cause an error. But it's strange it gives you a 404 instead of 500...

The second one doesn't work because `[R]` generate a new GET request, so you need to add the host or it will request the absolute path to the defined host and it, obviously, will not work. If you want to use [R], you should use:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://server.com/site_admin/api/$1.php [R]`

But it will not solve your problem. As I said, it will generate a new GET request and `.php` will be visible to your user.

Comment: doesn't work. Its not working even if i do a direct rewrite:

RewriteRule ^users$ users.php

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee, wait a second... I'm better reading your question and I see you have .htaccess inside server.com/site_admin/api and you're trying to rewrite the page server.com/site_admin/user. Is it right or is it a mistake? If it's right, you should move .htaccess on server.com/site_admin.

Comment: nope. I want to redirect api/users. All I want to do is get rid of the .php extension

Comment: either ways the point is: why does it redirect to /home/public and so on. By no means should it take the absolute path. I'd understand if it were entering an infinite redirect, but why redirect to a totally different directory

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee, It's weird. It works perfectly on my server: http://francescoruvolo.it/test/api/user. Do you have `AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf (if you have access to it)?

Comment: It looks like as black magic, I have the same problem, but(!) : 1) only in Firefox 2) only when Firefox in normal mode, in Private browsing it works fine 3) only for some concrete url